# bigquery bq mk command error while creating external table

Tags: google-bigquery

I use the following command to create external table from google drive file:
`bq mk --external_table_definition=./schema_file.json@CSV=https://drive.google.com/open?id=XXXXXXXXXX  brut__ideas.email_categorie`

I get the following error:
BigQuery error in mk operation: Field missing name

schema_file is the following:

```
[
"email_categorie":{
  "csvOptions": {
    "allowJaggedRows": false,
    "allowQuotedNewlines": false,
    "encoding": "UTF-8",
    "fieldDelimiter": ",",
    "preserveAsciiControlCharacters": false,
    "quote": "\"",
    "skipLeadingRows": 0
  },
  "schema": {
    "fields": [
      {
        "autodetect": false,
        "csvOptions": {
          "allowJaggedRows": true,
          "allowQuotedNewlines": true,
          "encoding": "UTF-8",
          "fieldDelimiter": ";",
          "skipLeadingRows": "1"
        },
        "schema": {
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "suffixe",
              "type": "STRING"
            },
            {
              "name": "categorie",
              "type": "STRING"
            }
          ]
        },
        "sourceFormat": "CSV"
      }
    ]
  },
  "sourceFormat": "CSV",
  "sourceUris": [
    "https://drive.google.com/open?id=XXXXXX"
  ]
}]
```

Actually, it works if I put only the schema field.

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated it on my project, it seems to be working fine.

> bq mk 
> --external_table_definition=SCHEMA_FILE@SOURCE_FORMAT=DRIVE_URI 
> DATASET.TABLE

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-drive#bq

Can you check your json file? It is possible that the source schema has an empty field name somewhere.

Comment: it works only if you don't put csv options.

Comment: I updated the question with the schema